# CSS div taking up the height of the background image

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, zurb-foundation-6

I have a header on my page where I have 2 divs and a title-bar. This is the html for it:

```
<div class="header row">
    <div class="frontpage-header-content">
         <div class="large-4 columns frontpage-header-content-div">
              <!-- some content -->
         </div>
         <div class="large-8 columns frontpage-header-image-div">
            <div class="frontpage-bg-image-wrapper">
               <div class="header-bg-image frontpage-header-hero">
                   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-bg.png">
                   <div class="hero-overlay overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-overlay overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <?php get_template_part('title-bar'); ?>
</div><!-- /.header -->
```

The right div has a div `frontpage-bg-image-wrapper`, which has a background image on large screens, that gets removed on smaller screens and replaced by an `image` element which is not visible on large screens. So, I am toggling `background image` for the `image` element based on screen size. That works fine in `chrome`, but when I test it in the `safari` the layout breaks. The `background image` is not visible on big screens, on smaller screens the `image` element becomes visible though. The problem is that the divs `.frontpage-header-image-div` and `.frontpage-bg-image-wrapper` don't take up any `height` in the safari, it is `0px` there and in the chrome it takes the `height` of the `image`. How can I fix that?
This is the css:

```
.frontpage-header-image-div {
  height: 100%;

  .frontpage-bg-image-wrapper {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/sfk/assets/images/sfk-bg.png') no-repeat;

    .header-bg-image img {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .hero-overlay {
    display: none;
  }
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.frontpage-header-hero {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.frontpage-header-content, .singlepage-header-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.frontpage-header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.frontpage-header-content-div {
  padding-left: 0;
}

@include breakpoint(medium down) {
  .frontpage-bg-image-wrapper {
    background: none !important;

    .header-bg-image img {
      display: block !important;
      min-height: 450px;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: 0 50%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .bg-overlay {
      display: none;
    }

    .hero-overlay {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }

  .frontpage-header-content, .singlepage-header-content {
    padding-top: 84px!important;
    position: relative;
  }

  .frontpage-header-content-div, .frontpage-header-image-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 84px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .header > .columns {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

So, if I set a `min-height` to anything, like for example `550px`, then it takes up the space, then you can see the background image, but that is not the solution since when I start resizing the screen to smaller size, the background is not taking up the whole height and the min-height should not be hardcoded but set somehow to the `100%` height of the `background` image.

This is how it should look like on large screens

[image]

And this is the unwanted effect that is happening when I resize the screen

[image]

The image doesn't go all the way to the top of the page.

Comment: Hey @Leff, there are around 260 lines of html/css you have posted. Could you try to simplify the test case? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Consider posting a jsfiddle that shows the issue. I tend to find people are more likely to help the less words there are to read. Also, the process of simplifying a test case often reveals a lot about the nature of the issue and makes it easier to ask more specific issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have cut the css only to the relevant one of the background image. I have also added images to show what is happening. I have tried to make a fiddle but it is not turning out the same.